Instagram opens the main page of the site instead of the link
I often send links to products via instagram messages. Some links open correctly, the rest open the main page of the site. Open Graph markup is fine, no dependence on the type of product and its description.
Example of a working link: https://cosmeticshop.md/yeppda-masca-regeneranta-din-tesatura-aha-bha-pha
Incorrectly working link: https://cosmeticshop.md/vs-fard-de-obraz-mat-blush-macaron
The main suspicion is that something is wrong with the pages, but code checks and validators do not reveal any abnormalities. I just don't have any ideas anymore.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fcosmeticshop.md%2Fvs-fard-de-obraz-mat-blush-macaron said you had the og:url set to https://cosmeticshop.md/, with the last scrape 14 hours ago. A re-scrape fetches the correct og:url now - so I guess you must have changed something recently?

@C3roe, That's right, it is. Originally the link was only to the home page for all pages. I may not have seen the patch changes because of the cache. Thanks, I didn't know that debugger existed.
I don't understand why some of the links do work and some don't. At the moment, the situation has not changed

Facebook caches scraping results, so if you only recently changed this, you will need to re-scrape those URLs to update the cache.

In summary: the problem is that Facebook caches data. If the page doesn't have the correct markup, the link won't open correctly either

Upvote helpful comment.
